# Zooming of html content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make and html file in which i am able to set what ever is in body should get zoomed to any specific value like 20%. something like the following piece of code (just a concept) . Is it possible to create html file zoom via css or the like if so kindly let me know how and it should be compatible with CHROME AND MOZILLA??

```
<body zoom="20%">
CONTENT HERE
</body>
```

Comment: Could you give us more details? Why are you trying to do this? What does it help achieve?

Comment: try this plugin http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

Comment: thanks undefined for your help kindly post as answer so i can credit you

Comment: @undefined This plugin looks really good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try `zoomooz.js` plugin.

http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

Comment: I think there must be more buttons more then "useful". This is awesome answer that I ever seen :) This is an amazing library and flashing lights in my mind...

Answer (score 4):

Zoom is not supported crossbrowser in CSS up to CSS3. You have the zoom-option in IE, and it might work in some other browsers, but I'd recommend you not to mess with it...

edit: however you could use zoom in IE and for the other browsers

```
transform :scale(0.5);
```

(with according browser prefixes)